# On the cohomology ring of the Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, cohomology, grassmannians

The basis of Schubert classes for the cohomology ring $H^*(\text{Gr}(m,N))$ of the Grassmannian of $m$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^N$ is indexed by $L(m,N-m)$, the poset of all partitions fitting inside a $m \times (N-m)$ box.  This is the quotient of the powerset $2^{m(N-m)}$ by the action of the wreath product $S(m) \wr S(N-m)$.  How does this come from the fact that $\text{Gr}(m,N) \cong U(N) / \big (U(m) \times U(N-m) \big )$?  Can this be extended to other homogeneous spaces?

Comment: Not the wreath product -- the direct product. (I suppose this is technically a particularly trivial wreath product.)

Comment: Allen, I believe you misunderstood his construction.  I think one copy moves the rows, and then there's a symmetric group on each row.  This lets you permute any set of boxes into a partition.

Comment: Ouch! I did indeed!

Answer (score 5):

The Schubert classes on $G/P$ are the classes of the Schubert varieties, which are the closures of the Schubert cells, each of which contains a unique $T$-fixed point. The $T$-fixed points on $G/P$ are the images of $T$-fixed points on $G/B$ (since $T$ acts on the fiber, which is a projective variety, hence itself has a $T$-fixed point by Borel's theorem).

Up on $G/B$, the $T$-fixed points are exactly of the form $N_G(T)B/B$, so indexed by the Weyl group $W_G = N_G(T)/T$. Down on $G/P$, they group together by the Weyl group $W_P = N_P(T)/T$, so they're indexed by $W_G/W_P$. Which is exactly what you observed in the $G/P =$ Grassmannian case.

(Actually you asked about compact groups, so $K/L$ where $K$ is compact and $L$ is compact of the same rank, which includes some cases like $S^4 = SO(5)/SO(4)$ that is not of the form $G/P$ for $G$ complex and $P$ parabolic. Then there's still a basis of "Schubert classes", indexed by $W_K/W_L$ similarly.)

Comment: But that's not exactly what he observed. The Weyl group of U(N) is the symmetric group S(N), so the Schubert decomposition W_G/W_P indexes the Grassmannian by the free quotient S(N) / (S(m) x S(N-m)). Whereas the quotient he discusses is {0,1}^(m(N-m)) / (S(m) wreath S(N-m)), which is not free. Both are in natural correspondence with the Young diagrams inside an m by N-m box. To see this for the free quotient, observe that it indexes all possible orderings of m moves across and N-m moves up.

Answer (score -3):

"[Schur-Weyl duality](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/evans/Zelditch_Schur_Weyl.pdf)" says that the permutation group S(k) is dual to the unitary group U(n).  Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality), Both of these groups act on the space $\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes  \dots \otimes \mathbb{C}^n$, with k factors.

- S(k) acts by permuting the factors $\sigma(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n)
  = v_{\sigma(1)} \otimes v_{\sigma(2)} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$
- U(n) acts like an n x n matrix on the $\mathbb{C}^n$, $g(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n)
  = g(v_1) \otimes g(v_2) \otimes \dots \otimes g(v_n) $

Schur-Weyl duality is the decomposition of this double-representation
$$ \mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n \otimes  \dots \otimes \mathbb{C}^n 
= \sum_D  \pi_k^D \otimes \rho_n^D$$
into tensor products of irreducible representations of S(k) and U(n).  D runs over young diagrams with k boxes and up to n rows.  Each of the young diagrams appears once.

Your questions clearly involved the duality between the permutation and unitary groups, though I couldn't explain to you how.  You might also see Fulton's book, [Young Tableaux](https://books.google.com/books?id=U9vZal2HCcoC).

Comment: I do not think that Schur-Weyl duality is relevant to this question.

Comment: Could be... certainly the Fulton *is* relevant.